# Minimal Ellipsoid in $R^{2}$; why is it the Ellipsoid 2 in the figure?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, conic-sections, convex-geometry, ellipsoids

It is stated in the book Convex Optimization, Boyd in page 47 that the ellipsoid 2 is the minimal because no other ellipsoid (centered at the origin) contains the point (top point) and is contained in Ellipsoid 2. However, I just draw an ellipsoid (red color) inside the ellipsoid 2. So, by which proof it is said that there is no ellipsoid inside ellipsoid 2 centered at origin passing through the top point?

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

[image: it is copied from the book: Convex Optimization, by Boyd]

Comment: In my version of the book, there is a third dot in this figure. Maybe that dot is missing in your version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal ellipsoid (with respect to area) centered at the lower dot  and containing the upper dot in your figure is the degenerate ellipsoid with smaller semiaxis $=0$ and one apex at the upper dot; in short: a segment covered twice. The ${\cal E}_2$ in your figure has no minimal properties whatsoever.

Comment: From the caption of the figure it seems to me that "area" is not used to define "minimal ellipsoid", but "minimal" is to be understood in the "subset" sense.